# How to pass null value to cursor through python

Tags: python-3.x

Cursor.execute ('call proc kan,NULL')

I can get the values but when i want to go for dynamic like json .I can't get it.Empty string and None value doesn't give output.

How to write cursor for Null using python and how i should pass it.it doesn't take like this also "Null" or'null' only it takes as per the first line .

Is there a way to get it ??

Comment: What is "Curso"?

Comment: conn=pymsql.connect() ,,cur=conn.cursor()